# jQuery Input Selectors with Square Brackets - iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I have this line of JS/jQuery:

```
if ( $( '[name=addons\\[' + addon_id + '\\]\\[selected\\]' ).prop( 'checked' )) {
```

Which works fine everywhere (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Android, Safari) except on Safari on iPhones.  But because there isn't any kind of error console (to my knowledge), I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this or to determine how it needs to be reformed to be compatible with iPhone.  Googling hasn't come up with anything for me.

Is there a way to make this work using the brackets for iPhone?  If not, I'll end up creating data attributes for the inputs and selecting them that way.  I may do that any way, but would really like to know if there's an answer for this.

Comment: give me an example of a html containing such an element

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="addons[25][selected]"  value="1" onclick="addon_toggle( $( this ).prop( 'checked' ), 25 );">`

Comment: You should be able to debug from Safari on a Mac or you can use the simulator. See https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787 and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Comment: It works properly on Safari on a Mac as well as on various iPhone simulators I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot an ending square bracket:

```
if ( $( '[name=addons\\[' + addon_id + '\\]\\[selected\\]]' ).prop( 'checked' )) {
```

Comment: Oh crap, I can't believe I did that! This was it.. thank you for spotting that. Looks like everything else was cool with the missing bracket for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Attribute value selector wrap the attribute value in quotes then you won't need to escape them using `\\`.

```js
var x = 25;
var value = $('[name="addons[' + x + '][selected]"]').val();
console.log(value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="addons[25][selected]" value="1">
```

---

However as per your current code, there is a missing closing `]` which create the problem which is pointed out by @Constantin

Comment: I'll give that a try.. looks like it would certainly help with readability.